# Azure SQL: Invalid Object Name using Powershell's "Invoke-sqlcmd" on Adventureworks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell, azure

I'm new to SQL, trying to query an Azure SQL Database (Adventureworks sample) using PowerShell's `Invoke-SQLCmd`.

When I try the following command in Powershell:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Customer;" -ServerInstance 
"<servername>.database.windows.net" -Username <username> -Password <password>
```

I get:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid object name 'SalesLT.Customer'.
```

Do I need to specify what Database that table is under?  Namely, "SQLDatabse" instead of "master"?  But when I add `Use SQLDatabase` to my query it throws another error:

```
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new     
connection to connect to a different database.
```

**Note:**  Executing these queries from SQL Server Management Studio gets me the  table with no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `-Database [dbname]` to the command parameters:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Customer;" 
    -ServerInstance "<servername>.database.windows.net" 
    -Username <username> -Password <password> -Database <dbname>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx

Comment: No prob.  I've never actually used it, but any time you connect to a server to query, it needs a reference to which database, and a quick look at the docs showed the param (servers can (and do by default) have multiple databases).