# Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid object name 'Inventar'

Tags: sql, powershell

So, i am tryingt to run a SQL-Query via Powershell with the Invoke-Sqlcmd-CMDLet. Pretty straight Forward:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $DBServer -Database $DBName -Username $DBUser -Password $DBPass
```

($Query is "`Select * FROM Inventar;`")

Now im getting an Error :

*Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid object name 'Inventar'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $DBServer -Database $DBName -Usernam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand*

ANYWAYS, i was able to run the Command with the following Query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

And it listed me all the Tables from the Database.

From there i've got the Table "Inventar", Kind of the error from This Question:

[Azure SQL: Invalid Object Name using Powershell's "Invoke-sqlcmd" on Adventureworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732009/azure-sql-invalid-object-name-using-powershells-invoke-sqlcmd-on-adventurewo)

Except for that i already have the -Database attribute.

Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: You probably need to qualify the schema where the table resides: `schema.Inventar`

Comment: I think the Schema contains of Domain\username, as it is shown like this under TABLE_SCHEMA, but when i set this in front of the Table (****** \ ******.Inventar) it wont accept the "\", so i tried it with the Username only and User@Domain, but this also wont work.

Comment: And if you use `[****** \ ******].[Inventar]`? Mind you, its a weird schema name that may need to be fixed.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is dumb. Good that i wasn't the One who set it up :-) I've set the Variable to 'Select * From "Domain\User".Inventar', that worked.. Thanks!

Comment: Can i set your Comment as answer anywhere..?

Comment: @GenesisIT They would need to post it as an answer.  Encourage by tagging them like I've tagged you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like `Select * FROM Inventar` sql server will assume the table is in the `dbo` schema. If it isn't, you'll get an error like you're getting. The solution is to qualify the schema: `(database).schema.table`. Your table is located in a schema named `domain\user`. Since a backslash is not allowed in an object name, you need to escape it. You can do that by surrounding the schema in `[]` or `""`:

`[****** \ ******].[Inventar]` or

`"****** \ ******"."Inventar"`.